# wso2esb rest api implementation

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-esb

Can anyone tell me step by step procedure on how to implement rest api in wso2esb server.

I have written the code in php & mysql to display student data in json format.

so when i visit following url in browser http://localhost/student/list_student i will get the list of user in json format

Now I want to get these json using wso2esb ?

And also do I need wso2 application server for restapi implementation?

Comment: What do you mean by `get these json using wso2esb`? You can write a webapplication with REST APIs and you can deployed it in WSO2 Application Server.

Comment: we are building an ESB architecture.for that we need 2 or more application(different language) connect with each other using wso2esb server.And One application in php and anther one .net so now i created web application in php and  How can I send the data to .net application using wso2esb?

Comment: Edit your question and update it with above details.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the detailed  WSO2 documentation on how to create a REST API using WSO2 ESB server at [1]. Please do post a separate question if you have any specific queries related to your implementation of the REST API. Thanks.

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Creating+APIs

Cheers,
Pubudu.

Answer (score 0):

According to your question you already have a backend which returns students data. You may use article [1] to create a REST API and expose it through the WSO2 ESB. Just call the existing end point and expose data in REST format through WSO2 ESB.

[1] http://wso2.com/library/articles/2013/12/restful-integration-with-wso2-esb/